# How to submit form value on .env or config/myconfig.php?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, environment-variables

I have a CRM for managing data, so far so good. I am thinking to add some `settings` extra option on my CRM, i am thinking for a *route* `/setting-value` and on this to display a form. I mean when a user go to this route to personalize CRM as his like, for example site-name, body-background-color, site-description, maybe to change db config. I know this config have to do with `.env` and `config/myconfig.php`, what i don't know is how to pass this submit form on `.env` or my config, how it really works. I have search on google but i didn't find any good documentation about this. Any one have an idea?

Comment: To make sure I understand your question: You want to edit the .env or config with your application?

Comment: Yes i think so.  I want to pass data from view form.

Comment: `.env` is used for your CRM settings (and shouldn't be available in a publicly available url), changes here will affect _your_ site. Store user settings in a database

Comment: Well, You should NEVER change the .env or config from a form on your application.

Comment: What I want to do is allow users to customize crm as they wish, so the site name, background color and some other styles. How can I do this? I was thinking to create a new config/myconfig.php and to add there a return[array] with filed  what i will let user to change  as they wish. Maybe is another way to do this?

Comment: @jokerr121 as commented by Brombeer, save the settings in the database..

Comment: @GertB.   @brombeer This is best way ? I have seen some other `CRM`  and they don`t save settings in the DB

Comment: @GertB. How about to give users the freedom to change their db as desired. I mean when they install this CRM first a setup wizard appears where the user set his db and also run the db migration he chooses?

Comment: The question is: Would it be a good idea to let the user change their DB? I don't think so...

Comment: @GertB. I am thinking if i will sell this db to other people , maybe not all have development knowledge and not all know how  to setup db configuration on .env file

Comment: Ok, so your CRM is _not_ a multiuser setup but a "standalone" app that you distribute to users? Each user gets their own "copy" of your CRM which they can then customize?

Comment: So post your form to a php script that writes to a certain file (.env, config/myconfig.php, resources/views/app.scss ...)

Comment: @brombeer Yes,its standalone CRM. But how can i pass script from form to `/config/myconfig.php` any example or documentaion?

Comment: You pass your form to a script, f.e. `editmyconfig.php` which reads/writes to file using PHP's [Filesystem Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php). Huge warning though! Altering config and (.env) files can royally screw up your app to a point where it is not usable at all! Be sure to know what you're doing! Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this package for .env editing geo-sot/laravel-env-editor

```
composer require geo-sot/laravel-env-editor
```

when you submit the form in your controller you can use these functions for various operations

```
 EnvEditor::getEnvFileContent($fileName='') 
 // Return The .env Data as Collection.
 // If FileName Is provided it searches inside backups Directory and returns these results

 EnvEditor::keyExists($key)
 // Search key existance in .env
 
 EnvEditor::getKey(string $key, $default = null)    
 // Get key value from .env,

  EnvEditor::addKey($key, $value, array $options = [])
  // Adds new Key in .env file
  // As options can pass ['index'=>'someNumericIndex'] in order to place the new key after an other and not in the end,
  // or ['group'=>'MAIL/APP etc'] to place the new key oat the end of the group 

  EnvEditor::editKey($key, $value)
  // Edits existing key value

  EnvEditor::deleteKey($key)
```